# Handler Does Not Execute Run

Tags: android

This feels like it should be a very simple task but I am having a lot of problems with it. In my program I have extended the WebView class for my own and am trying to add it to a layout programatically. Here is my code:

```
Looper.prepare();
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.post(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
            MyWebView webView = new MyWebView(context,1,2,3,4);
            appState.projectWebView.add(webView);
            addView(webView);
                   }
});
```

When I run this code it does not execute. I have no idea why. Thanks for you time.

Comment: Why do you have `Looper.prepare()` there?

Comment: I get this error when I try to run the program without it:

"12-29 00:10:37.513: E/AndroidRuntime(16641): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()"

Comment: I figured, you are trying to do this from the wrong thread, but there is not enough context in your code sample to gave you any other suggestion

Comment: These's not a whole lot of context to give really. This code is being run from inside a class that extends an AbsoluteLayout (I know, depreciated).

Comment: That class itself is ran ran inside a thread as it is creating view programatically. And basically that code inside the run() is never run. and I dont really see why.

Comment: It's _deprecated_, although its _depreciated_ as well... You need a `runOnUiThread` somewhere, or to create that `Handler` in your _UI thread_ and send it to the function that calls `post` on it.

Comment: Another way of looking at this - and this paradigm applies to Windows as well, *never, ever* modify a user control (for windows) or android view from a thread... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot create a `Handler` outside of an *UI thread*. Well, you can, but you will have to turn that thread into a message queue with much more than just `Looper.prepare()`.

What you need to do is pass an `Activity` to the class that contains the code in your sample, and call `runOnUiThread()` on it. Alternatively, you can pass a `Handler` created on a *UI thread*, for instance create it at the thread that runs your `Activity` UI, and then call `post` on that handler.

Note that this is awful advice, you seem to be trying to do things against the Android framework. But, without further information of what you are *actually* trying to do, there is no much that can be said.